# upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to upgrade my SQL Express to SQL Server 2008 and it gives me the following warnings. It always says that a previous installation exists but I already uninstall all things related to SQL Server 2008. I also tried doing a repair from the maintenance tool and it still fails. What should I do now?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to troubleshoot a failed upgrade to SQL Server 2008**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955399

To resolve this problem, you must examine the summary log file and perform the actions that are specified under the Final Result entry. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Locate the summary log file of the failed upgrade. Typically, the summary log file is located in the following folder:
     %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\
     The name of the summary log file resembles the following name:
     Summary_Server_Name-Node1_Date_Time.txt
2. Open the summary log file, and then locate the Final Result entry. This entry specifies the actions that you must take to complete the upgrade. For example, you may see an entry that resembles the following entry:
     SQL Server upgrade failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server using the following command line, and then rerun SQL Server Setup. Uninstall command line:
     setup /q /action=uninstall /instanceid=CLUSTER1 /features=SQLEngine,Replication,FullText
3. Investigate and resolve the problem that caused the failure. Then, continue with the remaining steps.
4. At the command prompt, move to the following folder:
     %Program Files%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap
5. At the command prompt, type the command that you identified in the Final Result entry in step 2, and then press ENTER. For example, if the Final Result entry resembles the example entry in step 2, type the following command, and then press ENTER:
     setup /q /action=uninstall /instanceid=CLUSTER1 /features=SQLEngine,Replication,FullText
6. After the unistallation is complete, restart the upgrade to SQL Server 2008.